Perl yancy auth with Bcrypt and dynamic salt
HI played around with Yancy the cms for Perl Mojolicious web framework.
When I tried to configure the salt for the password I could pass only static values:
    $self->yancy->plugin(
        'Auth::Password' => {
            allow_register => 1,
            register_fields => ['username', 'user_password'],
            schema          => 'User',
            username_field  => 'username',
            password_field  => 'user_password',
            password_digest => {
                type => 'Bcrypt',
                cost => 12,
                salt => '33cb8ead91234111',
            },
        }
    );

    


Is there any way in which I can make the yancy auth plugin read the salt for each password form the a db before login?

Seems like it is not supported, maybe you should avoid using Yancy::Plugin::Auth::Password and create your own authentication logic, or alternatively, extend the plugin to allow a check_password => sub {...} field

Is there anything stopping you from just calling a database before the yancy plugin setup?
